# What are the minimum hardware requirement to run Xcode 6 on mac mini?

Tags: xcode6, hardware

Can anybody please tell me the minimum hardware requirements to run "Xcode 6".I have installed the "Xcode 6" already but it is running too slow.I have a mac mini with 4 giga bytes Ram and  core 2 duo processor.Please suggest me any needful way.